# i have a log in issue the username and password is correct

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, session

here i am trying to log in with username "admin" and password "admin"
with form validation and putting those value in session
but while checking in database it is not returning any value????
my controller which verifies username and password is

```
 <?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('loginModel');
        $this->load->helper('string');
        $this->load->library("form_validation");
    }

    //login
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }


    Public Function authentication()        
    {
        $username=$this->input->post('username');
        $password=$this->input->post('password');        

        $this->form_validation->set_rules("username","Username","required");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("password","Password","required");

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            echo "Error";
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid User Name or PASSWORD!');
            redirect(site_url().'login');
        } else {
            $login_data = array(
                                "username"=>$username, 
                                "password"=>$password
                                );
            $authentication_response = $this->loginModel->user_authentication($login_data);

            if($authentication_response)
            {
                $username = $authentication_response['UserName'];
                $UserTypeId = $authentication_response['UserTypeId'];
                //put the user info on session
                $this->session->set_userdata("username", $username);
                $this->session->set_userdata("UserTypeId", $UserTypeId);

                if($UserTypeId == "1")
                {
                    redirect("dashboard");
                }
                if($UserTypeId == "2")
                {
                    redirect("dashboard");
                }

                if($UserTypeId == "3")
                {
                    redirect("userPanel");
                }

            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "Invalid User!!! Please check your user name or password correctly");
                redirect("login");
            }
        }
    }

    function logout(){
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(site_url().'login');
    }
}//end of class
?>
```

i am using sql server 2008 
UserName = admin Password =admin USERTYPEID=1

Comment: where is loginModel->user_authentication($login_data) function?

Comment: Please provide your loginModel code for review.

Comment: <?php 
class LoginModel extends CI_Model
{
 public function user_authentication($login_data)
 {

  $result_set = $this->db->get_where("Tbl_UserList", $login_data);
  if($result_set->num_rows() > 0)
  {
   return $result_set->row_array();
  }
  else
  {
   return FALSE;
  }
 }
}
?>

Comment: put the error flag with table name and take that raw query and run in MYSQL check what you will get

Comment: once enable error log and try to look into, may you find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this, I have improved some code and tested on my local server. it's working fine. Hope it will solve your problem. Here I assuming that your model works fine.

```
    public function authentication() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_password', 'Password', 'required');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

        $user_name = $this->input->post('user_name');
        $user_password = $this->input->post('user_password');

        $this->load->model('loginModel');
        $authentication_response  = $this->loginModel->user_authentication($user_name, $user_password);


        if ($authentication_response == TRUE) {

            $session_data = array(
                'UserTypeId' => $authentication_response['UserTypeId'],
                'username ' => $authentication_response['username']                    
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata('user_data', $session_data);            
            log_message('debug', 'This User Data Added To the Session: '. print_r($session_data, TRUE));

            if($UserTypeId == "1")
            {
                return redirect("dashboard");
            }
            if($UserTypeId == "2")
            {
               return redirect("dashboard");
            }

            if($UserTypeId == "3")
            {
                return redirect("userPanel");
            }

        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Invalid Username/Password.');
            log_message('error', 'This User Failed To log in: '. print_r($user_name, TRUE));
            return redirect('your_login_form');
        }
    } else {
        //Failed.
        log_message('error', 'Failed Login attempt Due to validation Error : '.print_r($user_name, TRUE));
        $this->load->view('your_login_form');
        // echo validation_errors();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You probably didn't return the response from the model. check again in the model or post the model code as well.

Comment: i think i have returned the value from model but when i echo the value it shows nothing.
here is the model


<?php 
class LoginModel extends CI_Model
{
 public function user_authentication($login_data)
 {

  $result_set = $this->db->get_where("Tbl_UserList", $login_data);
  if($result_set->num_rows() > 0)
  {
   return $result_set->row_array();
  }
  else
  {
   return FALSE;
  }
 }
}
?>

Comment: try `var_dump($authentication_response);`
`die;` just after  `$authentication_response = $this->loginModel->user_authentication($login_data);` what do you get.

Comment: bro it shows:
bool(false)
i was using xampp server back then but now using sql server
is that a issue??

Comment: then its clear in your model its written if  no row found it return false. no username password combination exists.

Comment: but i think both username and password matches.
i know the comnibation is not found i wanna know why is it not found??? 


      UserName           Password        UserTypeId
0 super             super             1
1 admin             admin               1


NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL